# React Function Higher Order Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Higher Order Component not working for functional component.

I am trying to create a sample functional HOC. I am using react hook useState and passing the state to the passed component. Below is my code

```
function HOC(WrapperComponent) {
  // outside of return function
  const [course] = useState({ id: 0, name: "Raja/Kondla" });
  return function() {
     return <WrapperComponent course={course} />;
  };
}

const Comp = HOC(({ course }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>HOC</div>
      <div>{course.id}</div>
      <div>{course.name}</div>
      <div>-------------------</div>
    </>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<Comp />, rootElement);
```

When I run it I am getting below error.

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

but if I put below code as HOC working fine.

```
function HOC(WrapperComponent) {
  return function() {
      // inside return function
    const [course] = useState({ id: 0, name: "Raja/Kondla" });
    return <WrapperComponent course={course} />;
  };
}
```

getting the result output:

```
HOC
0
Raja/Kondla
```

Can someone explain me what is the reason? and using functional HOC, will there be any performance impact?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should definitely go through this https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: ´HOC(({ course })´ Did you mean to write ´HOC((course)´ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HOC is a function which returns a react component this is why it works when you put the line inside the returned function component.

With that said, I would re-think the need for a HOC when working with hooks, the purpose of HOC's is to share logic across components, hooks solve the same challenge (in a much better way).

It's hard to understand what logic you tried to share with your HOC in your example but i would go for a [custom hook instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

From the DOCS:

> Traditionally in React, we’ve had two popular ways to share stateful
>   logic between components: render props and higher-order components. We
>   will now look at how Hooks solve many of the same problems without
>   forcing you to add more components to the tree.

Comment: Thanks for giving extra information. I thought only HOC and rener props are the only options for writing a reusable logic. But custom hook is the third option we are having.

Comment: @RajaKondla yeah, not just a third option (4th if you count the old mixins) but also the most powerful one.
With HOCS or render props you return a react element, with hooks (same as mixins) you can return anything you want. I think its a new primitive (building block) for react

Comment: Thanks for sharing information. I am thinking like if we want to use HOC or render props for re usability we should use class component, and we if want to use functional component for re usability we should use custom hooks. This is the difference I am finding right now. Is it correct? bare me if this question does not make any sence.

Comment: @RajaKondla Actually i don't think there is a valid use case to use classes at all if you work with react v16.8 (e.g the one with hooks). 
As i said, hooks are more powerful and flexible than HOCS or render props. You can do with hooks anything that HOCS or render props can do but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. You are giving more valid information. I will try to dig deep into react.  Once again Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Just to correct my previous comment, i said i don't see any valid use case to use classes in react. But there is one actually, currently [error boundries](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) can't be implemented with a function

Comment: So there is no suitable hook that can replace componentDidCatch event. Thanks. I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The **HOC** function that you have written appears to be wrong.

It is return a function when it should return a valid react component. A way to look at it would be, **what happens when your HOC gets called?** **What is it returning??** I think if you ask yourself these questions, you will get to the answer yourself.

```
function HOC(WrapperComponent) {
  // outside of return function
  const [course] = useState({ id: 0, name: "Raja/Kondla" });
  return function() {
     return <WrapperComponent course={course} />;
  };
}
```

This does not return a valid React component, rather it returns a function

On the other hand:

```
function HOC(WrapperComponent) {
  return function() {
      // inside return function
    const [course] = useState({ id: 0, name: "Raja/Kondla" });
    return <WrapperComponent course={course} />;
  };
}
```

This returns a valid React component.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. I am think of the error msg, but not thinking the other way.